# 2 lists in 1 listview android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create adapter for showing 2 lists in one listview. lists should be divided by image. This is the idea of XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Itemname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Itemname2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
```

I find it complicated to write custom adapters so any help is welcome.

Comment: Why not simply using 2 ListViews with an ImageView in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write your own adapter, just extend from the ArrayAdapter class and fill in the overriden methods.

This is just a quick example (it is not complete)

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private List list_one;
private List list_two;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects1, List objects2) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects1);
    this.list_one = objects1;
    this.list_two = objects2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //here you return the count of items your list will display
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_file_name, parent);
    TextView item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
    TextView item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Itemname2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    item1.setText(list_one.get(position));
    item2.setText(list_two.get(position));
    imageView.setImageResource(/*not really sure where you will be getting your image from*/);

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not quite clear on what you are trying to do, here's what I understand: 
You have two lists and you want to use corresponding data from the two lists to be shown in a single item of the ListView.

If that really is what you are trying to do, then create a third data model that represents a model of the data to be shown in each item of the ListView and use an ArrayList of this model to populate the items of the ListView.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)